# HTML DRAG AND DROP Items will not drag and drop back into original area

Tags: php, html, css, drag-and-drop

I built a small program that allows a user to drag and drop different items into different spots and save it as their personal home page. The problem I am having is that I need to send the generated values to specific users in PHPMyAdmin so that when they open their homepage up again it's the same. I am thinking this is a pretty simple solution, but I am fairly new to programming and need help. Below is the code. Feel free to copy and paste in order to find a solutions. Thanks for any help at all.

The format for the values when Save is clicked is

ID of ul | ID of li;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Drag and Drop to the columns</title>


<script type="text/javascript">
if(location.hostname.toLowerCase().indexOf('dhtmlgoodies') >=0) {
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-2042963-3']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; 
ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 
'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">

#footer{
    height:30px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:right;
    clear:both;
    padding-right:3px;      
    margin-top:2px;
    width:790px;
}
#footer form{
    margin:0px;
    margin-top:2px;
}
#drop_zone{ /* Main container for this script */
    width:790px;
    height:1100px;
    margin: auto;
    border:1px solid white;
    -moz-user-select:none;
}
#drop_zone ul{  /* General rules for all <ul> */
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding:2px;

}

#drop_zone li,#dragContent li{  /* Movable items, i.e. <LI> */

    list-style-type:none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 172px;
    height:62px;
    margin: auto;
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
}

li#indicateDestination{ /* Box indicating where content will be dropped - 
i.e. the one you use if you don't use arrow */
    border:1px solid #317082;


}


/* Right COLUMN CSS */
div#boxobjects{ /* Right column "Available students" */

    float:left;
    margin:auto;

    padding-top:50px;
    padding-bottom:0px;

    /* CSS HACK */
    width: 790px;   /* IE 5.x */
    width/* */:/**/770px;   /* Other browsers */
    width: /**/770px;

}
#boxobjects ul{ /* Right(Sources) column <ul> */
    height:auto;
    width:auto;

}

p{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
div#boxobjects div{
    border:1px solid #999;
}
div#boxobjects div ul{  /* right column <ul> */
    margin:auto;
}
#boxobjects div p{  /* Heading above right column */

    font-weight:bold;

    color:black;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
/* END LEFT COLUMN CSS */

#drop_zone .mouseover{  /* Mouse over effect DIV box in right column */
    background-color:#E2EBED;
    border:1px solid #317082;

}

/* Start main container CSS */

div#dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer{ /* Right column DIV */
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-left:90px;
    width:650px;

}
#dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer div{    /* Parent <div> of small boxes */
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border:1px solid #999;

    /* CSS HACK */
    width: auto;    /* IE 5.x */
    width/* */:/**/auto;    /* Other browsers */
    width: /**/auto;

    height: auto;   /* IE 5.x */
    height/* */:/**/auto;   /* Other browsers */
    height: /**/auto;

}


#dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer div p{  /* Heading above small boxes */
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    padding-left:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#317082;
    color:#FFF;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

#dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer ul{ /* Small box in right column ,i.e <ul> */
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    border:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    overflow:visible;

}

#dragContent{   /* Drag container */
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    display:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    z-index:auto;
}


</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
div#boxobjects{
    display:none;

}

img{
    display:none;
}
#drop_zone{
    border:0px;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">


/* VARIABLES YOU COULD MODIFY */
var boxSizeArray = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]; // Array indicating how many items 
 // there is rooom for in the right column ULs

var verticalSpaceBetweenListItems = 3;  // Pixels space between one <li> and 
//next
                                        // Same value or higher as margin 
//bottom in CSS for #drop_zone ul li,#dragContent li


var indicateDestionationByUseOfArrow = false;   // Display arrow to indicate 
//where object will be dropped(false = use rectangle)

var cloneSourceItems = false;   // Items picked from main container will be 
//cloned(i.e. "copy" instead of "cut").
var cloneAllowDuplicates = true;    // Allow multiple instances of an item 
//inside a small box(example: drag Student 1 to team A twice

/* END VARIABLES YOU COULD MODIFY */

var dragDropTopContainer = false;
var dragTimer = -1;
var dragContentObj = false;
var contentToBeDragged = false; // Reference to dragged <li>
var contentToBeDragged_src = false; // Reference to parent of <li> before 
drag started
var contentToBeDragged_next = false;    // Reference to next sibling of <li> 
to be dragged
var destinationObj = false; // Reference to <UL> or <LI> where element is 
dropped.
var dragDropIndicator = false;  // Reference to small arrow indicating where 
items will be dropped
var ulPositionArray = new Array();
var mouseoverObj = false;   // Reference to highlighted DIV

var MSIE = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE')>=0?true:false;
var navigatorVersion = navigator.appVersion.replace(/.*?MSIE 
(\d\.\d).*/g,'$1')/1;

var arrow_offsetX = -5; // Offset X - position of small arrow
var arrow_offsetY = 0;  // Offset Y - position of small arrow

if(!MSIE || navigatorVersion > 6){
    arrow_offsetX = -6; // Firefox - offset X small arrow
    arrow_offsetY = -13; // Firefox - offset Y small arrow
}


var indicateDestinationBox = false;
function getTopPos(inputObj)
{
  var returnValue = inputObj.offsetTop;
  while((inputObj = inputObj.offsetParent) != null){
    if(inputObj.tagName!='HTML')returnValue += inputObj.offsetTop;
  }
  return returnValue;
}

function getLeftPos(inputObj)
{
  var returnValue = inputObj.offsetLeft;
  while((inputObj = inputObj.offsetParent) != null){
    if(inputObj.tagName!='HTML')returnValue += inputObj.offsetLeft;
  }
  return returnValue;
}

function cancelEvent()
{
    return false;
}
function initDrag(e)    // Mouse button is pressed down on a LI
{
    if(document.all)e = event;
    var st = 
Math.max(document.body.scrollTop,document.documentElement.scrollTop);
    var sl = 
Math.max(document.body.scrollLeft,document.documentElement.scrollLeft);

    dragTimer = 0;
    dragContentObj.style.left = e.clientX + sl + 'px';
    dragContentObj.style.top = e.clientY + st + 'px';
    contentToBeDragged = this;
    contentToBeDragged_src = this.parentNode;
    contentToBeDragged_next = false;
    if(this.nextSibling){
        contentToBeDragged_next = this.nextSibling;
        if(!this.tagName && 
contentToBeDragged_next.nextSibling)contentToBeDragged_next = 
contentToBeDragged_next.nextSibling;
    }
    timerDrag();
    return false;
}

function timerDrag()
{
    if(dragTimer>=0 && dragTimer<10){
        dragTimer++;
        setTimeout('timerDrag()',10);
        return;
    }
    if(dragTimer==10){

        if(cloneSourceItems && contentToBeDragged.parentNode.id=='allItems'){
            newItem = contentToBeDragged.cloneNode(true);
            newItem.onmousedown = contentToBeDragged.onmousedown;
            contentToBeDragged = newItem;
        }
        dragContentObj.style.display='block';
        dragContentObj.appendChild(contentToBeDragged);
    }
}

function moveDragContent(e)
{
    if(dragTimer<10){
        if(contentToBeDragged){
            if(contentToBeDragged_next){

contentToBeDragged_src.insertBefore(
contentToBeDragged,contentToBeDragged_next);
            }else{
                contentToBeDragged_src.appendChild(contentToBeDragged);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    if(document.all)e = event;
    var st = 
Math.max(document.body.scrollTop,document.documentElement.scrollTop);
    var sl = 
Math.max(document.body.scrollLeft,document.documentElement.scrollLeft);


    dragContentObj.style.left = e.clientX + sl + 'px';
    dragContentObj.style.top = e.clientY + st + 'px';

    if(mouseoverObj)mouseoverObj.className='';
    destinationObj = false;
    dragDropIndicator.style.display='none';
    if(indicateDestinationBox)indicateDestinationBox.style.display='none';
    var x = e.clientX + sl;
    var y = e.clientY + st;
    var width = dragContentObj.offsetWidth;
    var height = dragContentObj.offsetHeight;

    var tmpOffsetX = arrow_offsetX;
    var tmpOffsetY = arrow_offsetY;


    for(var no=0;no<ulPositionArray.length;no++){
        var ul_leftPos = ulPositionArray[no]['left'];
        var ul_topPos = ulPositionArray[no]['top'];
        var ul_height = ulPositionArray[no]['height'];
        var ul_width = ulPositionArray[no]['width'];

        if((x+width) > ul_leftPos && x<(ul_leftPos + ul_width) && (y+height)> 
ul_topPos && y<(ul_topPos + ul_height)){
            var noExisting = ulPositionArray[no]
['obj'].getElementsByTagName('LI').length;
            if(indicateDestinationBox && 
indicateDestinationBox.parentNode==ulPositionArray[no]['obj'])noExisting--;
            if(noExisting<boxSizeArray[no-1] || no==0){
                dragDropIndicator.style.left = ul_leftPos + tmpOffsetX + 
'px';
                var subLi = ulPositionArray[no]
['obj'].getElementsByTagName('LI');

                var clonedItemAllreadyAdded = false;
                if(cloneSourceItems && !cloneAllowDuplicates){
                    for(var liIndex=0;liIndex<subLi.length;liIndex++){
                        if(contentToBeDragged.id == 
subLi[liIndex].id)clonedItemAllreadyAdded = true;
                    }
                    if(clonedItemAllreadyAdded)continue;
                }

                for(var liIndex=0;liIndex<subLi.length;liIndex++){
                    var tmpTop = getTopPos(subLi[liIndex]);
                    if(!indicateDestionationByUseOfArrow){
                        if(y<tmpTop){
                            destinationObj = subLi[liIndex];
                            indicateDestinationBox.style.display='block';

subLi[liIndex].parentNode.insertBefore(indicateDestinationBox,subLi[
liIndex]);
                            break;
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(y<tmpTop){
                            destinationObj = subLi[liIndex];
                            dragDropIndicator.style.top = tmpTop + tmpOffsetY 
 - Math.round(dragDropIndicator.clientHeight/2) + 'px';
                            dragDropIndicator.style.display='block';
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(!indicateDestionationByUseOfArrow){
                    if(indicateDestinationBox.style.display=='none'){
                        indicateDestinationBox.style.display='block';
                        ulPositionArray[no]
 ['obj'].appendChild(indicateDestinationBox);
                    }

                }else{
                    if(subLi.length>0 && 
dragDropIndicator.style.display=='none'){
                        dragDropIndicator.style.top = 
getTopPos(subLi[subLi.length-1]) + subLi[subLi.length-1].offsetHeight + 
tmpOffsetY + 'px';
                        dragDropIndicator.style.display='block';
                    }
                    if(subLi.length==0){
                        dragDropIndicator.style.top = ul_topPos + 
arrow_offsetY + 'px'
                        dragDropIndicator.style.display='block';
                    }
                }

                if(!destinationObj)destinationObj = ulPositionArray[no]
['obj'];
                mouseoverObj = ulPositionArray[no]['obj'].parentNode;
                mouseoverObj.className='mouseover';
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

/* End dragging
Put <LI> into a destination or back to where it came from.
*/
function dragDropEnd(e)
{
    if(dragTimer==-1)return;
    if(dragTimer<10){
        dragTimer = -1;
        return;
    }
    dragTimer = -1;
    if(document.all)e = event;


    if(cloneSourceItems && (!destinationObj || (destinationObj && 
  (destinationObj.id=='allItems' || 
 destinationObj.parentNode.id=='allItems')))){
        contentToBeDragged.parentNode.removeChild(contentToBeDragged);
    }else{

        if(destinationObj){
            if(destinationObj.tagName=='UL'){
                destinationObj.appendChild(contentToBeDragged);
            }else{

  destinationObj.parentNode.insertBefore(contentToBeDragged,destinationObj);
            }
            mouseoverObj.className='';
            destinationObj = false;
            dragDropIndicator.style.display='none';
            if(indicateDestinationBox){
                indicateDestinationBox.style.display='none';
                document.body.appendChild(indicateDestinationBox);
            }
            contentToBeDragged = false;
            return;
        }
        if(contentToBeDragged_next){

  contentToBeDragged_src.insertBefore(
 contentToBeDragged,contentToBeDragged_next);
        }else{
            contentToBeDragged_src.appendChild(contentToBeDragged);
        }
    }
    contentToBeDragged = false;
    dragDropIndicator.style.display='none';
    if(indicateDestinationBox){
        indicateDestinationBox.style.display='none';
        document.body.appendChild(indicateDestinationBox);

    }
    mouseoverObj = false;

}

/*
Preparing data to be saved
*/
function saveDragDropNodes()
{
    var saveString = "";
    var uls = dragDropTopContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL');
    for(var no=0;no<uls.length;no++){   // LOoping through all <ul>
        var lis = uls[no].getElementsByTagName('LI');
        for(var no2=0;no2<lis.length;no2++){
            if(saveString.length>0)saveString = saveString + ";";
            saveString = saveString + uls[no].id + '|' + lis[no2].id;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('saveContent').innerHTML = '<h1>Ready to save 
these nodes:</h1> ' + saveString.replace(/;/g,';<br>') + '<p>Format: ID of ul 
|(pipe) ID of li;(semicolon)</p><p>You can put these values into a hidden 
form fields, post it to the server and explode the submitted value 
there</p>';

}

function initDragDropScript()
{
    dragContentObj = document.getElementById('dragContent');
    dragDropIndicator = document.getElementById('dragDropIndicator');
    dragDropTopContainer = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
    document.documentElement.onselectstart = cancelEvent;;
    var listItems = dragDropTopContainer.getElementsByTagName('LI');    // 
Get array containing all <LI>
    var itemHeight = false;
    for(var no=0;no<listItems.length;no++){
        listItems[no].onmousedown = initDrag;
        listItems[no].onselectstart = cancelEvent;
        if(!itemHeight)itemHeight = listItems[no].offsetHeight;
        if(MSIE && navigatorVersion/1<6){
            listItems[no].style.cursor='hand';
        }
    }

    var mainContainer = 
document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer');
    var uls = mainContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL');
    itemHeight = itemHeight + verticalSpaceBetweenListItems;
    for(var no=0;no<uls.length;no++){
        uls[no].style.height = itemHeight * boxSizeArray[no]  + 'px';
    }

    var leftContainer = document.getElementById('boxobjects');
    var itemBox = leftContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL')[0];

    document.documentElement.onmousemove = moveDragContent; // Mouse move 
event - moving draggable div
    document.documentElement.onmouseup = dragDropEnd;   // Mouse move event - 
moving draggable div

    var ulArray = dragDropTopContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL');
    for(var no=0;no<ulArray.length;no++){
        ulPositionArray[no] = new Array();
        ulPositionArray[no]['left'] = getLeftPos(ulArray[no]);
        ulPositionArray[no]['top'] = getTopPos(ulArray[no]);
        ulPositionArray[no]['width'] = ulArray[no].offsetWidth;
        ulPositionArray[no]['height'] = ulArray[no].clientHeight;
        ulPositionArray[no]['obj'] = ulArray[no];
    }

    if(!indicateDestionationByUseOfArrow){
        indicateDestinationBox = document.createElement('LI');
        indicateDestinationBox.id = 'indicateDestination';
        indicateDestinationBox.style.display='none';
        document.body.appendChild(indicateDestinationBox);


    }
  }

  window.onload = initDragDropScript;

    function cursor_hand(x)
  {
    x.style.cursor = "pointer";
  }

  function cursor_default(x)
  {
    x.style.cursor = "default";
  }

  function hide_element(nm)
  {
    var table_selector = "#" + nm;
    $(nm).toggle(); 
  }

  </script>
</head>
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/asV3.css" />



<?php

// Print a customized message:
echo "<p>Welcome to NorseGIS, {$_SESSION['first_name']} 
{$_SESSION['last_name']}!</p>";
$user_num = $_SESSION['user_number'];





?>



</script>
<body>

 <h1><p style="text-align:center;"><?php echo "{$_SESSION['first_name']} 
 {$_SESSION['last_name']}"?>'s Homepage</p></h1>
 <br>



 <div id="drop_zone"> <!-- entire drag drop section -->
    <div id="dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer" > <!-- all of the boxes to drop in -
 ->
    <!-- ONE <UL> for each "room" -->
    <div style = "width:200px; height:90px;">

        <ul id="box1" style = "width:200px; height:90px;">

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style = "width:200px; height:90px;">

        <ul id="box2" style = "width:200px; height:90px;"></ul>
    </div>
    <div style = "width:200px; height:90px;">

        <ul id="box3" style = "width:200px; height:90px;">


        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style = "width:200px; height:90px;">

        <ul id="box4" style = "width:200px; height:90px;"></ul>
    </div>
    <div style = "width:200px; height:90px;">

        <ul id="box5" style = "width:200px; height:90px;">

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style = "width:200px; height:90px;">

        <ul id="box6" style = "width:200px; height:90px;">

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style = "width:200px; height:90px;">

        <ul id="box7" style = "width:200px; height:90px;">

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style = "width:200px; height:90px;">

        <ul id="box8" style = "width:200px; height:90px;">

        </ul>
    </div >
    <div style = "width:200px; height:90px;">

        <ul id="box9" style = "width:200px; height:90px;">

        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <form action="aPage.html" method="post" ><input type="button" 
onclick="saveDragDropNodes()" value="Save Changes"></form>
<br>
<form method="post"><input type="button" onclick="hide_element(table)" 
value="Edit"></form>

<div id="boxobjects"> <!-- entire left column -->
    <div>
        <p onclick = "hide_element(table);" style = "margin:auto; text-
 decoration: underline; font-size:20px;" onmouseover="cursor_hand(this)" 
onmouseout="cursor_default(this)"><?php echo "{$_SESSION['first_name']}"?>'s 
Options</p>
        <br>
        <div id = "table" style = "display:none;">
    <ul id="allItems">
        <li id="node1"><a href = "snow_events.php" style = "text-decoration: 
underline; text-align:center;">Snow Removal</a></li>
        <li id="node2"><a href = "weatherradar.php" style = "text-decoration: 
underline; text-align:center;">Weather Radar</a></li>
        <li id="node3"><a href = "warranty.php" style = "text-decoration: 
underline; text-align:center;">The Warranty</a></li>
        <li id="node4">Student D</li>
        <li id="node5">Student E</li>
        <li id="node6">Student F</li>
        <li id="node7">Student G</li>
        <li id="node8">Student H</li>
        <li id="node9">Student I</li>
        <li id="node10">Student J</li>
        <li id="node11">Student K</li>
        <li id="node12">Student L</li>

    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="footer"> <!-- box with save button -->

</div>
<ul id="dragContent"></ul>
<div id="dragDropIndicator"></div>
<div id="saveContent"></div>
</body>
//</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I can't see any PHP code, expect the welcome message.

Comment: I should have only added the question about making the item able to be dropped back into the original div. That is my main problem at the moment. Thanks @Twinfriends